# Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix of order $n$ and $A^2=0$ . Is it necessarily true that $A=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

> Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix of order $n$ and $A^2=0$ . Is it necessarily true that $A=0$ .

My approach :

I tried to experiment with some $2\times 2$ matrices but never gotten any far .

Now, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix) says that there exists a diagonal matrix $D$ and orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that $D=Q^t A Q$ .
So $D^2=Q^t A^2 Q=0$ . As $D$ is diagonal matrix with real entry we get $D=0$ .

So $A=QDQ^t =0 $ 
I think my proof is correct . I just want know if there is any way to prove this without citing any big theorems or in more elementary way . The problem is quoted from a part of the web-text that only used elementary definitions like what a symmetric matrix is . So i'm curious if there is an elementary solution to the problem .

Comment: You can use $Tr\,A^2=\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}a_{ji}=\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}^2$, so $Tr\,A^2=0$ iff $A=0$.

Comment: @user8268 : This is so brilliant . Thank you .

Comment: Are the coefficient necessarily from $\Bbb{R}$?  If $\Bbb{C}$ is allowed then consider: 
$$A = \left(\begin{matrix}1 & i \\ i & -1\\\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: Nothing was mentioned specifically . The problem was from this link  http://nptel.ac.in/courses/122104018/node25.html   . The author never used any field other than $\mathbb{R}$ . So i guess it was implicit .

Comment: @SumanKundu I guess so.  I asked because I could only prove it for the reals.  A little playing produced that example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An easy and natural way to do this is using inner products.  Note that if $A^2v=0$, then $$0=\langle v,A^2v\rangle=\langle A^Tv, Av\rangle=\langle Av,Av\rangle=\|Av\|^2$$ which implies $Av=0$.  In particular, if $A^2=0$, we get $Av=0$ for all $v$ and so $A=0$.

If you don't like the language of inner products and want something entirely in the elementary language of matrices, use the definition $\langle v,w\rangle=v^Tw$.  So the equation above becomes $$0=v^TA^2v=v^TA^TAv=(Av)^TAv$$ and now you observe that for any vector $w$, $w^Tw$ is just the sum of the squares of the entries of $w$ and so can only be $0$ if $w=0$.

Answer (score 2):

If $A \neq 0$, then there are some $1 \leq i,j \leq n$ ensuring that if $a_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)$ element of $A$ then $a_{ij} \neq 0$. The matrix $A$ is by assumption symmetric; so $a_{ij} = a_{ji}$. If $b_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)$ element of $A^{2}$, then $b_{ij} \geq a_{ij}^{2} > 0$.

Comment: Could you expand that?  In particular why $b_{ij} = a_{ij}^{2}$.

Comment: @badjohn, Thanks for it.